# Android table creation error for multiple tables i thing on create method is went wrong somewhere

Tags: android

ONE TABLE I CAN CREATE THERE IS NO ERROR IN EMULATOR ALSO
THIS IS MY SqliteHelper.JAVA CLASS

i am able to create one table but not able to create two table there is no error is showing im using DB browser to check

```
package com.example.administrator.billing;   
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="billing";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_PRODUCT_MASTER ="product_master";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_SALES ="sales_master";

    //product master fields
    public static final String mstr_id="mstr_id";
    public static final String mstr_product_code="mstr_product_code";
    public static final String mstr_product_name="mstr_product_name";
    public static final String mstr_cgstper="mstr_cgstper";
    public static final String mstr_sgstper="mstr_sgstper";
    public static final String mstr_cessper="mstr_cessper";
    public static final String mstr_defrate="mstr_defrate";

    // salebill
    public static final String slbl_id="slbl_id";
    public static final String slbl_product_code="slbl_product_code";
    public static final String slbl_qty="slbl_qty";
    public static final String slbl_rate="slbl_rate";
    public static final String slbl_tot="slbl_tot";
    public static final String slbl_cgst="slbl_cgst";
    public static final String slbl_sgst="slbl_sgst";
    public static final String slbl_cess="slbl_cess";
    public static final String slbl_net="slbl_net";

    public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        //SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME_PRODUCT_MASTER+" (mstr_id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,mstr_product_code integer,mstr_product_name text not null," +
                " mstr_cgstper double(18,2), mstr_sgstper double(18,2),mstr_cessper double(18,2),mstr_defrate double(18,2))");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME_SALES+" (slbl_id INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT,slbl_product_code integer,slbl_qty double(18,2)," +
                " slbl_rate double(18,2), slbl_tot double(18,2),slbl_cgst double(18,2),slbl_sgst double(18,2)" +
                ",slbl_cess double(18,2),slbl_net double(18,2))");

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+TABLE_NAME_PRODUCT_MASTER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+TABLE_NAME_SALES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insertProductMaster(String Mstr_product_code,String Mstr_product_name, String Mstr_cgstper, String Mstr_sgstper, String Mstr_cessper,String Mstr_defrate){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(mstr_product_code,Mstr_product_code);
        contentValues.put(mstr_product_name,Mstr_product_name);
        contentValues.put(mstr_cgstper,Mstr_cgstper);
        contentValues.put(mstr_sgstper,Mstr_sgstper);
        contentValues.put(mstr_cessper,Mstr_cessper);
        contentValues.put(mstr_defrate,Mstr_defrate);
        long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME_PRODUCT_MASTER,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

AND THIS IS MY MAIN ACTIVITY.JAVA

```
package com.example.administrator.billing;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SqliteHelper myDb;
    Button salebill;
    Button product_master;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb=new SqliteHelper(this);
        product_master=(Button) findViewById(R.id.prduct_master);
        salebill=(Button) findViewById(R.id.salebill);
        salebill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SaleBill.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        product_master.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent producti = new Intent(MainActivity.this, product_master.class);
                startActivity(producti);
            }
        });

      }
}
```

Android table creation error for multiple tables i thing on create method is went wrong somewhere

Comment: please post error log

Comment: remove the caps in your question.

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: there is no error showing but not creating table. if i delete database and re created its creating but if i create one table while creating database and another next time its not creating